# concatenated sum of two arrays of integer

Tags: java, int, parseint

i am getting such kind of output

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:9)

we have taken two arrays of size m and n now we have to take m and n size array
and we have to concatenate the each array and perform the addition of the two array which we got 
for example:

> m=4,n=5

- 1 2 4 5
- 5 7 3 12 6
- output is ->574371

> 1245 + 573126=574371

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code Here

Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
int i,j,cc,dd;
int m=s.nextInt();
int n=s.nextInt();
int a[]=new int[m];
int b[]=new int[n];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    a[i]=s.nextInt();

}
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    b[j]=s.nextInt();
}
String s1=Arrays.toString(a);
String s2=Arrays.toString(b);

cc=Integer.parseInt(s1);
dd=Integer.parseInt(s2);

System.out.print(cc+dd);



    }
}
```

Comment: What are you looking for sir? Any errors? optimization ?

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to String[]
String a[]=new int[m];

Comment: Indeed, look at the line of code. You start defining an array of strings and you are creating an array of ints.

Comment: You should append all values from 1st array to one string, and all values from 2nd array to 2nd string, then convert to int using `Integer.parseInt()` those new string that have appended values and it will work

Answer (score 3):

Another approach : You can try by taking advantage of string concatenation.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your Code Here

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, cc, dd;
        int m = s.nextInt();
        int n = s.nextInt();
        // int a[]=new int[m];
        // int b[]=new int[n];
        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            a += s.next();

        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b += s.next();
        }
        // String s1=Arrays.toString(a);
        // String s2=Arrays.toString(b);
        //
        cc = Integer.parseInt(a);
        dd = Integer.parseInt(b);

        System.out.print(cc + dd);

    }
}
```

Comment: I like this more, rather than using arrays

Answer (score 1):

For string concatenation in loop it is better to use `StringBuilder`:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    final Function<Integer, Integer> readValue = digits -> {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
            buf.append(scan.nextInt());

        return Integer.parseInt(buf.toString());
    };

    int m = scan.nextInt();
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(readValue.apply(m) + readValue.apply(n));
}
```

Or fully use `Streams`:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    final Function<Integer, Integer> readValue = digits ->
            Integer.parseInt(IntStream.range(0, digits)
                                      .map(i -> scan.nextInt())
                                      .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                                      .collect(Collectors.joining()));

    int m = scan.nextInt();
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(readValue.apply(m) + readValue.apply(n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build number from arrays and can do sum like below:
like convert int array to String and then String to integer by using parseInt() method.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr1 = {1 ,2, 4 ,5};
    int[] arr2 = {5 ,7, 3 ,12 ,6};

    long sum = getNumber(arr1) + getNumber(arr2);
    System.out.println(sum);

        }

        public static int getNumber(int[ ] arr) {
            String number ="";
            for(int i : arr) {
                number = number + i;
            }
            return Integer.parseInt(number);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the code, I suggest you stop a scanner stream using some stop word, this example uses `empty string` ~ `""`
It's not necessary to parse a string value to an integer for each iteration.
After reading, I do the next steps.

First, the code replaces all spaces between numbers according to your example.

Second, filters your input values using the regular expression.

Third, then we have got only numbers, and we should convert them to integer values without any problems.

The last step is the summary, it counts a sum of your inputs and printing result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String bufferLine;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !Objects.equals(bufferLine = scanner.nextLine(), "")) {
        arrays.add(bufferLine);
    }

    int sum = arrays.stream()
            .map(s -> s.replace(" ",""))
            .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
            .sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```